# Unexpected: OpenCart Database Truncating After SomeTime

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, opencart, opencart2.x

I've a opencart website and have two domain like example.com and example2.com.  First website in running like example.com and working fine. When I have copied all the code files and import database to example2.com and running same code set and database. After some time all the database is truncating.

Note that both domain are on same server and I'm using godaddy cpanel hosting.

Please help me to figure out this problem.

Comment: What do you mean by truncating? Is data not going into the second database after a set period of time?

Comment: example2.com database is truncating and lost all the data. Both website running separately and have separate database and running independently.

Comment: If they are running separately and have separate database then it looks like you have not change the example2.com /config.php and admin/config.php where you have to change the database setting. 
define('DB_DRIVER', 'mysqli');
define('DB_HOSTNAME', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'databaseusername');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'databasepassword');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'databasename');
define('DB_PORT', '3306');
define('DB_PREFIX', 'oc_');

Comment: I've changed all the settings and data is deleting from example2.com i.e newly host website